# debugging technique for tracking down a Security Sandbox Violation in AIR/Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I've inherited a project and am getting a "Security Sandbox Violation" notice. This is a complicated project with lots of modules, data binding, changeWatchers and little documentation (aka *a mess*).

The project is entirely desktop based (or supposed to be). I'm still trying to get a handle on the code. If I can find where/what is triggering this alert notice, I can fix it but so far I haven't a clue.

Are there debugging techniques for tracking down a Security Sandbox Violation in AIR/Flex?

This is the error notice I am getting:

> *** Security Sandbox Violation *** SecurityDomain 'file:///Users/Red/Documents/02%20Commercial%20Work/Books/Demo/Time/EventBitmaps/4M_01.png'
>   tried to access incompatible context 'app:/Colors.swf'

Comment: What code is triggering that security sandbox error?  Generally security sandbox errors occur when trying to access a domain other than the one the SWF is served from; but that shouldn't apply in an AIR app.  Perhaps the app does not have access to the "File" directory it is trying to access?  But, how is it trying to access it?  Is that file on your machine?

Comment: That's the thing - there are contentLoader calls in lots of different modules so I don't know what code is triggering the error. The path the error cites is local & within the directory that other stuff is getting loaded from. Is there any way to trigger a breakpoint on getting a Security Alert or otherwise get access to the call stack?

Comment: No way I know of to trigger a breakpoint on getting the error.  USually security sandbox violations fail silently, so you probably don't even have a stack trace to review.  You're going to have to review the code to discover the source.

Comment: one thing you said... lots of modules... So my thought is if you are loading a module... then another... by default they are loaded into separate application domains and security domains.  If they send events to each other .. and one tries to access the bitmapdata of an image from another, you could see that.  If you can find it, (as @www.Flextras.com said may be a toughie), you could set the loaders to use a context with SecurityDomain.currentDomain to prevent it) see [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/SecurityDomain.html)

Comment: @JasonReeves - Thanks Jason. I'll check out the link. The code is a bit of a pinball machine - bouncing all over - so I was hoping to cut through it by setting a conditional breakpoint on the domain error. Sigh.

Comment: Unfortunately, even clicking on an input textField in a loaded module which doesn't have app privs will produce this error. Usually it relates either to attempting to access .stage or the focus manager (though I'm sure there could be many other causes - the fact that it's coming from the png makes these my first suspicion).